# 404 error when called the default jsp page, able to call index.html

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

**Environment** - Eclipse IDE, running tomcat server by creating an instance of it in Eclipse.

**Overall Setup** - I have deployed 2 web application(A & B) in Tomcat server, where A calls B & things happens. This works fine most of the time.

#### Orignal Issue Scenario

1. Lets say I leave my machine unattended for couple of hrs & then comeback restart the server(has 2 apps deployed in it).
2. Open the browser, I am able to call app A, but not able to establish connection with app B.

On digging further, I tried to load a jsp page from app B with url -

```
http://localhost:8080/testrunner/login
```

but can't do that[image: HTTP Status 404]. However I am able to call the index.html from this url -

```
http://localhost:8080/testrunner/
```

***Current Solution*** - The way to overcome this issue is to simply redeploy app B & I am good to go i.e. I am app A calls app B.

***Question*** -

1. But my Issue is that why should I get this error & how to overcome this issue without redeploying app B.
2. Also when I do my current solution , the login page loads in eclipse's browser, but the same is not loaded in FF browser. Not sure what's missing here.

Any help/clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From provided details I can say

You have deployed application as `testrunner`. So, `http://localhost:8080/testrunner/` calls `index.html` from the `welcome-file-list` given in deployment descriptor.

```
404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the
client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was
requested.
```

When you do `http://localhost:8080/testrunner/login`, Server could not find any mapping named `\login`. So, Check You have mapping for "`/login`" in your application called "testrunner"

Comment: ,yes, I have mapped /login on the <pre>welcome-file-list</pre> in the WebContent > Build.xml in "testrunner" application.But somehow I cannot still access that page from browser but it comes up fine in eclipse's browser.

Comment: @TahirShabbir: What is mapped with /login. Can you provide snippet of web.xml in your post ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have got the login page to come up for the testrunner app. The way I did that is that I deleted & recreated jsp files & re mapped them. Still my first issue is not resolved.

Comment: @TahirShabbir: Can you edit the question and provide more details on what is mapped with "/login" and how you are forwarding the request

Comment: after deploying the application outside of Eclipse's tomcat instance, we are not able to reproduce the issue. So I think I am not going to dig into this further. Thanks for the follow up on this. Appreciate that.